# No IP information in hostvars

Tags: vagrant, ansible

My Playbook:

```
- hosts: master
  gather_facts: True
  become: True
  tasks:
    - set_fact: headnode={{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0] }}

- hosts: slave
  become: True
  tasks:
    - debug: msg={{ hostvars.master }}
```

And no fact `headnode` there. Am I missing something? Also, `hostvars.master` doesn't contain `['ansible_eth0']` So is all the documentation wrong?

This doesn't work also: `hostvars['master ']['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address']`
And this: `hostvars[groups['master'][0]]['ansible_eth0']`

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables

hostvars.master:

```
ok: [slave0] => {
    "msg": {
        "ansible_check_mode": false,
        "ansible_ssh_host": "xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com",
        "ansible_ssh_port": 22,
        "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "/root/.ssh/id_rsa",
        "ansible_ssh_user": "vagrant",
        "ansible_version": {
            "full": "2.2.2.0",
            "major": 2,
            "minor": 2,
            "revision": 2,
            "string": "2.2.2.0"
        },
        "group_names": [
            "master"
        ],
        "groups": {
            "all": [
                "master",
                "slave0"
            ],
            "master": [
                "master"
            ],
            "slave": [
                "slave0"
            ],
            "ungrouped": []
        },
        "inventory_dir": "/xxx/.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory",
        "inventory_file": null,
        "inventory_hostname": "master",
        "inventory_hostname_short": "master",
        "omit": "__omit_place_holder__fb9f90a73039d94f14c1a1f0af132f1c36b9fb4a",
        "playbook_dir": "/xxx/ansible"
    }
}
```

Comment: The facts are not gathered (none of the facts, i.e. not only IP address is missing, everything is missing). Don't ask me why. Check your log.

Comment: How do you run the playbook? Is it executed by Vagrant? Are you sure you run the playbook against two machines when they both exist? And, for example, that the execution is not limited to one machine at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `- debug: msg={{ hostvars.master }}` task shows only facts available from the inventory file. It does not contain the IP address nor quite a number of other facts that should be gathered from the remote machine by the regular setup module.

Now, as you seemingly run the playbook in Vagrant provisioning, it likely runs the playbook two times, first on `master` only, then on `slave0` only. Vagrant by default passes a `--limit` argument to Ansible limiting the scope to the currently-provisioned machine only.

In result, when the playbook is being executed against `slave0`, the first play (set to run on `hosts: master`) is not executed and the facts from hosts belonging to the `master` group (in this case from the host also named `master`) are not gathered.

---

You can either change the scope of the provisioning for the `slave0` machine in Vagrantfile by setting `ansible.limit = 'all'`.

Or you can run `ansible-playbook` afterwards pointing to the Vagrant-generated inventory file.